# Discrete mathematics - algorithm complexity question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

What is the largest N for which one can solve in one minute an algorithm which requires N! operations if your computer can only do 5000 operations per second?

Comment: Well, how many operations is that in one minute? Which values of $N!$ are smaller than that number?

Answer (score 2):

As @Misha points out above:  Number of operations available:  $5000 \cdot 60 = 300,000$.

Find the largest $n$ such that $n! \le 300,000$.